# Why does Bisq not upgrade Tor addresses silently

Tags: adoption, marketing, bisq, promotion, usability

I started up Bisq today. It had a pop-up  with elaborate instructions on how to "upgrade Tor v2 addresses to v3". This involved shutting down Bisq, deleting a dir and then starting it back up again.

Why not simply do it automatically in Bisq, without the user ever having to know about it?

Comment: If you have UX feedback for Bisq I'd open an issue on the Bisq repo or discuss it with the GUI developers on Bisq. Asking whether "Bitcoiners" want Bitcoin to stay obscure is like asking whether Americans want to stay Democratic or Republican. I'm sure there are some people who want Bitcoin to stay obscure but I'm pretty sure Bisq wants to onboard as many users as possible and continuously improve the UX as long as it doesn't negatively impact security, privacy.

Comment: I will say that I have been working on making my own seqwit wallet. And there is no official documentation. Ultimately I had to examine the source code and ask questions here. If you contrast that to other crypto's like etherium, then yes it feels like the community wants to stay obscure.

Comment: @noone392 1. Its not "etherium", Its Ethereum. 2. Ethereum community has no Bisq like DEX which has fiat markets since few years 3. Half of the questions on Ethereum Stackexchange are unanswered if I look at first page (sorted by newest) 4. This question was asked earlier and responded. Not sure why is it posted again. I will answer again below.

Comment: @noone392: We're a bit off-topic here, and it might be better to create another topic for that, but I assume you have seen the corresponding BIPs?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Bisq the simple answer is developer shortage. No, there is no hidden motive. You are very welcome to help with development **and get compensated for it** by the Bisq DAO.

Answer (score 0):

> I started up Bisq today. It had a pop-up (one of countless over the years...) with elaborate instructions on how to "upgrade Tor v2 addresses to v3". This involved shutting down Bisq, deleting a dir and then starting it back up again.

IIUC, this pop-up was added in https://github.com/bisq-network/bisq/pull/5573 to help users. If you have issues or any suggestions, feel free to contribute by creating issues or pull requests in Bisq repository.

> Do Bitcoiners secretly *want* Bitcoin to stay obscure?

Nobody can answer this question and it does not make sense. There is no "the bitcoin community", there are lots of people in different communities associated with bitcoin. They can have different opinions on things.

> Bisq, after all, is crucial in its role as the only non-KYC, decentralized Bitcoin exchange in the world. (Seriously, it is the only one. If you don't get that, I don't have the time to convince you otherwise.)

You should also research about Bisq development. It is similar to other FOSS projects and even has a DAO.